# Not working Self-signed certificate nginx on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nginx, server, ssl-certificate

Not working Self-Signed ssl certificate on Nginx server.

This is /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user fatboy;
http {
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  include      /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  server {
     location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
     }
  }
  server{
     listen 443;
     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /home/fatboy/public.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /home/fatboy/key.pem;
     location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
       }
  }
}
worker_processes 5;
events {
  worker_connections 2000;
}
```

This is sudo ufw status:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        DENY        Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   DENY        Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

For self-signed certificate I used this command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out public.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=Company Name/OU=Org/CN=www.bux-bot.ru"
```

Comment: How can you say it's not working? What's the output when you open https://localhost

Comment: @Objectobject it's not localhost. domain - bux-bot.ru . U can successfully open [http](http://bux-bot.ru), but [https](https://bux-bot.ru) just not loading.

Comment: Try this `sudo ufw allow 443` then check the status of `sudo ufw status`

Comment: @Objectobject 
`Status: active`
`To                         Action      From`
`--                         ------      ----`
`OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere`
`443                        ALLOW       Anywhere`
`Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere`
`OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)`
`443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)`
`Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)`

And there is a new error on https "The web page at https://46.229.215.47/ may be temporarily unavailable or permanently moved to a new address.
"

Comment: While accessing `https://bux-bot.ru/` it working now

Comment: @Objectobject hmm, rly? [not working for me](http://prntscr.com/npsqjh)

Comment: Yes, it's working. perhaps try from other device or in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

So in your case, your firewall is blocking port 443.

You can open port running `sudo ufw allow 443` and check status `sudo ufw status`

Now open https://bux-bot.ru/